# ubuntu hangs on shutdown/Restart after suspend

Tags: suspend, shutdown, freeze, restart

I know it seems that i have asked a Repetitious question. but it is really different!

there is no problem with restart, shutdown and suspend at first. but if I suspend the system just once, after that I can't restart or shutdown!

imagine --> you turn the laptop on --> no problem with restart or shutdown !

but(!) --> if you suspend the system and come back --> after that if you try to restart the system or shut it down, the system freezes!

I have ubuntu 16.04.3 lts. 20gb swap, 30gb root and 100gb home beside windows 10.

I have removed unity and installed gnome 3. notice that The problem was already there before changing unity to gnome 3.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

My Toshiba Satellite c660 works perfectly either shut down or suspend and wakes perfectly but only on battery power.
On AC power it appears to shut down or appears to suspend but then will not re-start until the power button is used to kill it.
I now simply disconnect the AC cord a couple of seconds before shut down/suspend and the laptop will then re-start as intended.
I've tried all the other solutions but until someone with the knowledge to adjust the software comes along this is what I do.
Hope this low-tech solution works for others.